# Does the scope for 'Alter Any Database' operate similar to 'Create Any Database'?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, alter-database

Does the scope for 'Alter Any Database' operate similar to 'Create Any Database', as in, only those databases created by Login-A under the 'Create Any Database' umbrella can be altered, and not the other databases on the server?

Answer (score 3):

Why is this so hard to test for yourself? As `sa` or similar:

```
CREATE LOGIN Jake WITH PASSWORD = N'x', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
GO
GRANT ALTER ANY DATABASE TO Jake;
GO
CREATE DATABASE IBelongToAaron;
GO
```

Now log in as Jake:

```
CREATE DATABASE IBelongToJake;
GO
ALTER DATABASE IBelongToJake SET RECOVERY FULL; -- success!
GO
ALTER DATABASE IBelongToAaron SET RECOVERY FULL; -- success!
```

So no, `ALTER ANY DATABASE` works as advertised, which is probably why it's not called `ALTER ANY DATABASE THAT I CREATED OR OWN`.